# Is there a VB.net equivalent of the following C# code

Tags: c#, vb.net

Please what is the VB.net equivalent of the following C# code:

```
internal static unsafe void DistortedDraw(byte* sourceBuffer, Bitmap displacementMap, Bitmap destBitmap) {
        int sourceWidth = destBitmap.Width, sourceHeight = destBitmap.Height;
        BitmapData previewData = destBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, destBitmap.PixelFormat);
        int sourceDataStride = previewData.Stride;
        int sourceBPP = destBitmap.PixelFormat.ToString().Contains("16") ? 2 : destBitmap.PixelFormat.ToString().Contains("24") ? 3 : destBitmap.PixelFormat.ToString().Contains("32") ? 4 : 0;

        if (displacementMap == null) {
            unsafe {
                byte* previewScan0 = (byte*)previewData.Scan0;
                byte* sourceScan0 = (byte*)sourceBuffer;
                for (int y = 0, yofs = 0, invyofs = (sourceHeight - 1 - y) * sourceDataStride; y < sourceHeight; y++, yofs += sourceDataStride, invyofs -= sourceDataStride) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < sourceDataStride; x += 4) {
                        *(int*)(previewScan0 + yofs + x) = *(int*)(sourceScan0 + invyofs + x);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        destBitmap.UnlockBits(previewData);
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: VB.Net does not support pointers.

Comment: I honestly don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: @Sebastian: "Translate my code for me" is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for code to be translated from one language to another. StackOverflow is not a code translation service.


Comment: @ Eric Lippert I have tried to convert this and i am unable to. I guess asking for help is "Off-Topic" on StackOverflow. If i could work through it myself, i would not ask

Comment: @EricLippert I know. But when I wrote my comment there was only one line of code visible - the method signature. Of course with the method body appended it seems inappropriate.

Comment: @CharlesO: You are correct: vague requests for "help" are off topic. *Specific* technical questions are on-topic.

Comment: @EricLippert I've worked it out. I can use dim x As IntPtr in VB.net. The first comment above and Alejandro's answer below were helpful. What value have you added here with your comments? Some of us are just trying to learn, please don't discourage others from helping. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is NO direct equivalent in Visual Basic. The root problem is that VB.NET does not support the unsafe keyword or pointers.

The best you can do is to inspect what that method does and find a way to replace the pointer variable with some other 100% managed construct.

Comment: i have edited the question, to include the full c# function.